# Python Jira API Screen error for source and region fields

Tags: python, api, jira, python-jira

I am trying to create Jira issue using Python-Jira API but getting screen error for source and region fields.Please help me to resolve the same.

Error:

```
Exception Value:    
JiraError HTTP 400
 text: Field 'source' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.
url: http://jira.corp.inmobi.com/rest/api/2/issue
response headers = {'X-AUSERNAME': 'Vivek.Sinha', 'X-ASEN': 'SEN-2505611', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'OK', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'X-AREQUESTID': '777x24903741x3', 'X-ASESSIONID': '6dg96h', 'Connection': 'close', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Date': 'Mon, 30 May 2016 12:57:34 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'}
response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"source":"Field 'source' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."}}
```

code:

```
def create(request):
    if 'name'  in request.GET:
            n=request.GET['name']
            options={'server':'http://jira.com'}
            jira=JIRA(options,basic_auth=('username','passwd'))
            root_dict={
            'project':{'key':'TS'},
            'issuetype':{'name':'Issue'},
            'summary':'Test',
            'description':'Test',
            'source':[{'name':'Walk-ups'}],
            'type':{'name':p},
            'region':{'name':'INDIA'},  
            }
            my_issue=jira.create_issue(fields=root_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have correct configuration?
Chceck this post: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/265902/answers/19694532

Comment: Its related to field name as in our internal Jira had code-name for service and region.BTW thanks